# Memory Leak with Google Ads in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, admob

I'm geting so much problem with performance of Google Admob in WP8, so now I wrote a simple project to test. I only have 2 page an a user control which'' contain the admob.

My scerano here's navigate between MainPage and SecondPage repeatly, both with button in app or hardware back key.

My app start with 40Mb memory used. I tried to implement IDispose for the user control and clear the navigation history each time after navigate, but the memory heap grown really fast and my App crashed after 20+ naviate turn. If I stop navigate, I notice that memory did decrease after a minute, but not so much (ex. from 140 down to 120). So now I just don't know how to avoid this problem ?

This's the MainPage.xaml (and the same with the second page):

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <-- a control from coding4fun to show memory couter directy in screen-->
    <coding4fun:MemoryCounter/>

    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Content="SecondPage" Width="200" Height="100" 
                Click="Button_Click"/>
        <test:GoogleAds x:Name="googletest" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="60"/>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

This's the MainPage.xaml.cs (and the same with the second page):

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Unloaded += MainPage_Unloaded;
    }

    void MainPage_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("unload mainpage");
        googletest.Dispose();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));           
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (NavigationService.CanGoBack || NavigationService.CanGoForward)
            while (NavigationService.BackStack.Count() > 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("remove backentry");
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            }                    
    }      
}
```

Here is the GoogleAds user control (with default xaml which I'' not post here).

```
public partial class GoogleAds : UserControl, IDisposable
{
    public GoogleAds()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadAd();
    }
    AdView ad;
    AdRequest request;
    void LoadAd()
    {
        ad = new AdView()
        {
            AdUnitID = "test-key",
            Format = AdFormats.Banner
        };
        request = new AdRequest();
        request.ForceTesting = true;
        ad.ReceivedAd += ad_ReceivedAd;
        ad.FailedToReceiveAd += ad_FailedToReceiveAd;
        LayoutRoot.Children.Add(ad);
        ad.LoadAd(request);
    }

    void ad_FailedToReceiveAd(object sender, AdErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("fail ad");
    }

    void ad_ReceivedAd(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("success ad");
    }

    //
    bool disposed = false;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        if (disposing)
        {

        }       
        if (ad != null)
        {
            ad.ReceivedAd -= ad_ReceivedAd;
            ad.FailedToReceiveAd -= ad_FailedToReceiveAd;                
            ad = null;                                
        }
        disposed = true;
        Debug.WriteLine("dispose googleads");
    }
    ~GoogleAds()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: try disposing googlead not in unloaded but in onnavigatingfrom

Comment: @jackjop I'm not sure what's the diffirent ?

Comment: I don't know but there is a possibility that the page never unloads or after page is unloaded googleads cannot be disposed maybe. everything can be happen in wp. it's still unstable in my opinion

Comment: Have You found any solutions?